# Creating Android layout for supporting 4" and 5" inch screen size issue

Tags: android, layout

I've refer'ed more documents and also come across [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and many post that seems to be my problem. But i would like to get more specific suggestions or answer here.

Problem is, i have developed my home screen for 5" inch phone(like nexus 4) , so it's looking pretty well on it. When i run the same app in 4" inch phone(like nexus s), the home screen got not looks like in 5" phone. It's so weird and some of buttons, views are not fitted. What should i do now?  I've also tried to create a separate layout folder like layout-320dp and layout-normal. Both screens comes under the HDPI part, so i can't create a separate layout folder. Added, i used more image view's on my home screen and given more specific number values for padding purpose.If i reduce image size in drawable folder means i can get pretty UI on 4" inches too.

My_home_screen_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:name=".ActionbarFragment" >   

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/sty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"           
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/_splash_blank_screen"
        />   

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
        android:singleLine="false"          
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/girl_home"               
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#675836"
        android:textStyle="bold" />     


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel_weather"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
        android:singleLine="false"   
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLabel"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"   
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/girl_home"               
        android:textSize="14sp"            
        android:textColor="#675836"
        android:textStyle="bold" />   


    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_calendar"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reference_calendar_button_icon_home"
          android:paddingTop="90dp"
          android:paddingRight="1dip"
          android:singleLine="true"             
          android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />



 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/girl_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:paddingTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"   
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mix_match_toast"     
        android:singleLine="true"  
         />     


 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/today_outfit"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"                    
        android:layout_below="@+id/girl_home"  
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"                          
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"  
         />


 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reference_calendar_button_icon_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="55dp"              
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/today_outfit"              
        android:singleLine="true"                
        android:src="@drawable/btn_calendar_home" /> 

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closet_button_icon_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"  
        android:layout_below="@id/text_calendar"        
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/today_outfit"      
        android:src="@drawable/ic_closet_home_new" /> 


      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_notes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:paddingTop="150dp"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"    
        android:src="@drawable/btn_search_home"            
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" /> 

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_weather"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                     
        android:singleLine="false"            
        android:layout_below="@+id/chat_button_icon_home" 
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dip"          
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:text="TODAY'S FORECAST"
        android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/today_look"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                     
        android:singleLine="false"            
        android:layout_below="@+id/today_outfit" 
        android:paddingLeft="65dip"  
        android:paddingTop="1dip"        
        android:textSize="12sp"        
        android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel_weather_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/today_look"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"                  
        android:singleLine="false"           
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chat_button_icon_home"                 
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textColor="#675836"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_window"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
          android:layout_below="@+id/window_button_icon_home"                        
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:paddingLeft="260dp"              
          android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/chat_button_icon_home"
          android:layout_width="70dp"
          android:layout_height="70dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/today_look" 
          android:layout_marginTop="35dp"  
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"             
          android:singleLine="true"
           />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/window_button_icon_home"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/today_outfit"   
          android:layout_below="@+id/text_inspire"  
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"      
          android:paddingLeft="30dp"              
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:src="@drawable/btn_window_shop_new" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/inspire_idea"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"                       
          android:paddingLeft="30dp"
          android:paddingTop="25dp"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/text_closet"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/today_outfit" 
          android:src="@drawable/btn_inspire_home" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_closet"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/closet_button_icon_home"              
          android:paddingTop="1dip"
          android:paddingLeft="275dp"
          android:singleLine="true"             
          android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text_inspire"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/today_outfit"
          android:paddingLeft="270dp"
          android:paddingTop="-10dp"
          android:singleLine="true"             
          android:textColor="@color/text_highlight"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you worked with weightSum property to manage your views? Better if you place some code here

Comment: Paste your screenshot of what you have and layout xml sources.

Comment: @SanketPandya, dilix  thanks for your reply. I've added my layout source code.

Comment: @AhmadRaza sorry, i can't share the screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can create layouts folders depending upon `height` and `width`. For example- `layout-w360dp, layout-w480dp or layout-h480dp or layout-h600dp`. Then set Views in those layouts according to your requirement.

**Edit**-

For `Nexus-4` create `layout-w720dp` and for `Nexus-S` and `Nexus-One` create `layout-w480dp`. This works now.

Comment: you mean i can create a layout folder like layout-w360-hdpi, layout-w480dp-hdpi based on the width and height right ?

Comment: @chain yes you can. I always do this.

Comment: @chain see this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Thank @kanwalijit. let you know the result after testing.

Comment: Mine pleasure. Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work for me. could you please suggest me to design separate layout for nexus 4 and nexus s.Actually i have designed layout for nexus 4 but it's not compatible with nexus s and one.

Comment: Sorry that was wrong way you have to create layouts. check my updated answer.

Comment: w480dp means screens with width 480dp and above that. And w720dp for width 720 and above that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommened you to use linearlayout as parent layout and use weights as weights 
    divide screen in equal parts.no need to create any extra layout folder.

Comment: My home screen looks like grid view images, so it doesn't make sense if i change it to linear layout.

Comment: no you are wrong,bcs you just have to put grid in linearlayout and rest inflator will do